# Missing import statement - for element (used with in WebStorm with Protractor)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, webstorm, ui-automation

I'm getting this WebStorm warning:

```
Method expression is not of Function type.
Missing import statement.
Insert 'import {element} from "Protractor"'
```

I am not getting the warning for the `element.all` shown here:

```
 localB.patientData = function(b, no) {
            switch(b) {
                case 'personalHistoryAdd':
                    return element.all(by.css('#\\31 3f65373-7f31-4581-b839-8281e0d5dd0d > button')).get(0);
                case 'familyHistoryAdd':
                    return element.all(by.css('#\\31 3f65373-7f31-4581-b839-8281e0d5dd0d > button')).get(1);
                case 'surgicalHistoryAdd':

            }};
```

But I do get it for `element` here:

```
        localB.vitals = function(b, no) {
            switch(b) {
                case 'heightInput':
                    return element(by.css('#height'));
                case 'weightInput':
                    return element(by.css('#weight'));
                case 'temperatureInput':
                    return element(by.css('#temp'));
            }
        };
```

These are in the same file. TLDR, I do not get the warning with `element.all` but I do get it with just `element`, which is really odd!

It fixes it if I add Insert `'import {element} from "Protractor"'` at the beginning of the file but the script won't execute, so this is not a solution.

Isn't it a possibility to configure WebStorm to fix this?

This is how WebStorm/Libraries looks like, for me:

```
ON  @types/jasmine  Global
ON  @types/jest Global
ON  @types/karma    Global
ON  @types/mocha    Global
ON  @types/node Global
ON  @types/protractor-helpers   Global
ON  @types/selenium-standalone  Global
ON  @types/selenium-webdriver   Global
ON  protractor  Global
ON  selenium    Global
ON  selenium-webdriver  Project
ON  HTML    Predefined
ON  HTTP Response Handler   Predefined
ON  Node.js Core    Predefined
ON  wbk-automation-protractor/node_modules  Predefined
```

If I disable these:

```
ON  protractor  Global
ON  wbk-automation-protractor/node_modules  Predefined
```

Then I get the `Missing Import Statement` for `by.css` as well, for example.

Comment: I got this response from Webstorm:

in protractor typings, element is defined as a ES6 module, and thus has to be imported, so this warning is correct and expected (same is true for by, browser, etc.). You can disable JavaScript | General | Missing import statement inspection in Preferences | Editor | Inspections, or suppress it for needed statements by adding // noinspection ES6ModulesDependencies comment above them

But by and browser, they work. It's just element. I'm waiting for a reply from them.